# How to solve MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'

Tags: ibm-mq

I am writing to an MQ queue from Java and I am intermittently get the error response below. I am using IBM MQ version 9.

What could be the cause of this as its intermittent and the queue / queue manager being written to exists and was running during this time.

```
[INFO ] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.752+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - Finished establishing a connection to DB
[INFO ] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.752+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - init
[INFO ] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.758+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - 5. Before calling write.selectQMgr()
[INFO ] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.864+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - 6. After selecting Queue Manager name
[DEBUG] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.876+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - ReasonCode:2085
[DEBUG] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.877+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - Completion Code:2
[ERROR] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.877+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - Message:MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2085'
        at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.open(MQDestination.java:322) ~[com.ibm.mq.jar:9.0.0.5 - p900-005-180821]
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueue.<init>(MQQueue.java:236) ~[com.ibm.mq.jar:9.0.0.5 - p900-005-180821]
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.accessQueue(MQQueueManager.java:3288) ~[com.ibm.mq.jar:9.0.0.5 - p900-005-180821]
        at custom.MQWriteFile.write(MQWriteFile.java:364) ~[PGPEncryptedSOAPWMQWriter.jar:?]
        at custom.MQWriteFile.<init>(MQWriteFile.java:221) [PGPEncryptedSOAPWMQWriter.jar:?]
        at custom.PGPEncryptedSOAPWMQWriter.main(PGPEncryptedSOAPWMQWriter.java:69) [PGPEncryptedSOAPWMQWriter.jar:?]
[INFO ] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.879+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - LogStatusInDB
[DEBUG] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.911+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - Reason Code Desc:MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME
[DEBUG] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.911+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - Completion Code Desc:MQCC_FAILED
[DEBUG] 2020-06-13 22:48:03.911+0300 [main] [e5643f16-94ea-436f-ad71-54bee1c91381] MQWriteFile - Returning with:3
```

Comment: Is the queue a temporary queue? What is the queue name?

Comment: Can you post your application code?

Comment: @MoragHughson, we are not using a temporary queue. Layout is that the source app writes to an alias queue which then routes the traffic to a local queue on another queue manager

Comment: @Shashi, I am unable to post the code cause I dont have access to it. But I can check the logs

Comment: Does the source app always connect to the same queue manager when writing to the alias queue or is there different source queue managers that it connect to?

Comment: @JoshMc, the source app is always connecting to the same queue manager

Comment: I suggest you turn on trace on java app, for example `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.limit=10485760 -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.count=2 -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=/some/path/to/some/file.trc`, this will do a looping trace where there would be 2 10MB trace files.  Stop it once you have reproduced the intermittent 2085 and review the trace to see if there is anything interesting around the time the `MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME` is produced.  If needed you can open a case and send this to IBM.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, let me do this and will revert once I have the results

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the cause will be logic flow related with variables or objects falling out of scope, then coming back into scope with reset / default values.

The traces that you are running, will tell you which values your code is actually using. You will most likely need to add logging into your application to determine why the values are being lost.